# Why am I able to push and send/receive pull requests but not on the contributor list in github?

Tags: github

I'm been working in a team of four. I'm in the collaborator list. I'm able to commit, push, send pull requests and merge in our repo. My teammates can see my changes, but everyone is on the contributor list except me.
I double checked my email address, make sure the email I used in my local setting is the same with my default email in the github account.
We have changed the owner of the project once, and I'm still using the old url. Is this the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the github has a complex rule for you be considered as a contributor. Here's the doc of it.
https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile
You have to commit to the main/default branch or make pull requests. To commit into other branches won't count.
Also, to use the old project url is definately one problem. In the project insight, everyone's profile is linked with their username. While mine is only a username with no user icon.

I think I just accidentally hit into one of the corner cases, but I'm still very confused of this design pattern.